# "No provider for RadioControlRegistry" in angular 2 what provider should I add?

Tags: html, angular, provider

What provider should I add in provider component?

```
<div class="radio">
<input let match id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="true" [(ngModel)]="isMatching"  (click)="isMatching(match.value)" >
```

Here's my console output:
[image: error message in console.]

Comment: If you add `FormsModule` (or `ReactiveFormsModule`) to `imports: [...]` of your current module, the error should go away.

Comment: i didn't add FormsModule or ReactiveFormsModule in my code

Comment: Then this is what you should do ;-)

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? In version 12.2 simply adding the FormsModule to the module that has my component, isn't enough. I still get that error.

Comment: actually that was an old questions it was angular 2 rc5 and the answer worked well for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `FormsModule` to `imports`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule]
  ...
})
class MyModule {}
```